# Add class to element when an element is scrolled over

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm having a container containing a top menu. But when this container is scrolled by width 60 px I need a class to be added to the top menu, but it doesn't do it now.

I have this Jquery:

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#case-container').scrollTop()>60) {
         $('.case-header').addClass('sticky')
    } else if ($('#case-container').scrollTop()<60) {
         $('.case-header').removeClass('sticky')
    }
});
```

How can I fix this to make it work?

Comment: What is not working? Adding class or scroll? And can you post the html also?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net, so that we can see what's going wrong? By the way, unless you want to do nothing when `.scrollTop()` is exactly 60 you can just use a plain `else { ...` case, you don't need `else if` with a condition that is the opposite of the initial `if` condition.

Comment: [Could be helpful](http://heera.it/jquery-sticky-menu-plugin), looks you want a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

The elements scrollTop doesn't change, only the element that is being scrolled will have the scrollTop changed.

Note that for setting the scrollTop, some browsers use body, other html, so the usual fix is to check both like so `$('body, html').scrollTop(100)`, but for getting, window (or in this context `this`) should work :

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop()>60) {
         $('.case-header').addClass('sticky')
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop()<60) {
         $('.case-header').removeClass('sticky')
    }
});
```

As a sidenote, you could shorten it to

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.case-header').toggleClass('sticky', $(this).scrollTop() > 60);
});
```

Comment: +1, but I would prefer `$('.case-header.sticky').removeClass('sticky');` or `$('.case-header.sticky').toggleClass('sticky', $(this).scrollTop() > 60);` but not necessary.

Comment: Thanks! But now it sticks when window top is scrolled down, I want it to stick when the #case-container is scrolled down, instead of window

Comment: @Kim - but does #case-container even have a scrollbar, the element being scrolled in the event handler is clearly the window, so how can you scroll down only one element without scrolling the window ?